# overwrite has_many association to use two different owner_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: User and Notification.

```
User has_many :notifications
Notification belongs_to User
```

This is the describe code for notifications

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| namespace  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| key        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| value      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and these are some examples of notifications:

```
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+-------+
| id | user_id | namespace | key             | value |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+-------+
|  4 |      -1 | facebook  | launch_campaign |     1 |
|  5 |      -1 | facebook  | add_video       |     1 |
|  6 |      -1 | facebook  | add_image       |     1 |
|  7 |      -1 | twitter   | add_image       |     1 |
|  8 |      -1 | twitter   | add_video       |     1 |
|  9 |      -1 | twitter   | launch_campaign |     1 |
|  10|      21 | facebook  | add_video       |     0 |
|  11|      1  | facebook  | add_image       |     0 |
|  12|      10 | twitter   | add_image       |     0 |
|  13|      12 | twitter   | add_video       |     0 |
+----+---------+-----------+-----------------+-------+
```

the rows with the user_id = -1 are the default values, and every time the user overwrite the default value I add a row for that user and the namespace and action and the overwritten values.

Now i rails if I do

```
User.notifications
```

I would only get the notifications that have the user_id in them, but I also want to get the default notifications (use_id = -1) that the user has not overwritten. Any ideas how to do that?
Also any more advice on this design/topic is appreciated :)!

this is also a more detailed explanation of my design 
[Database + data model design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303854/data-base-data-model-design-patter/11304238#11304238)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could try to use `:conditions` options for your association:

```
has_many :notifications, :conditions => 'user_id = #{id} OR user_id = -1'
```

**NOTE:** this is NOT interpolation string, it will be interpolated in the context of an object, not the class.

**Update.**

Or even `:finder_sql` will be good enough. Anyway, a lot of interesting lives [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

Comment: So the string interpolation didn't work for me. I put it in single quate and I also tried %q for finder_sql but everytime I do user.notifications I get
 
  Notifications Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `notifications`.* FROM `notifications` WHERE `notifications`.`user_id` = 1 AND (user_id = #{id} OR user_id = -1)
any ideas?

Comment: Acutally I realized for rails 3 I need to use lambdas, :conditions => lambda {"user_id = #{self.id} OR user_id = -1"}

Comment: Thanks for the details. Never saw it before in Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

Try a scope in your User class instead of using the has_many relationship directly.  Something like this:

```
scope :all_notifications, joins("left join notifications n on n.user_id=users.id").where(["n.user_id=? OR n.user_id=?", self.id, -1])
```

Comment: Thanks I started going down this route

Comment: I didn't work. I realized scope is a class method, so I can't use it for the current User object. So when I use that code I get NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for #<Class:0x00000008192438>